# Vector space decomposition through tensor product

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

Let $U$ and $W$ be two vector spaces with respective bases $B_{U}$ and $B_{W}$ over the same field $\mathbb{F}$. As far as I know, I can always build the tensor product space $U\otimes W$ of $U$ and $W$, that is a vector space which has as basis the set of all $u\otimes w$ with $u\in B_{U}$ and $w\in B_{W}$.

Moreover this approach can also be generalized to an arbitrary number $k$ of spaces $V_i$ with $i=1,\dots,k$, from which one can construct the tensor product space $V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes \dots \otimes V_k$.

Unfortunately I haven't found anything useful in the literature and I was wondering if it's possible to think the other way around.

**Questions:**

- Starting from a vector space $V$, is it possible to find a decomposition of the space $V$ as a tensor product $V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes \dots \otimes V_k$ of smaller spaces $V_i$ with $i=1,\dots,k$?
- If this is not always possible, when is it? My intuition tells me that this isn't always possible, unless the dimension of the space $V$ is factorizable.

Comment: your intuition is certainly correct as the number of element in a basis equals the dimension of the space. In a non-canonical way, all vector spaces $V$ are $V\simeq k^r$ ($k$ being the ground field and $r$ begin a nonnegative integer). At this point, if $r=r'r ''$ then $V\simeq k^{r'}\otimes k^{r''}$, so the decomposition is always possible, but in a very non-canonical way.

Comment: Vector spaces of the same finite dimension are isomorphic though not canonically. So if dim $V_1$ dim $V_2$... dim $V_k$$=$$dim V$, then they are isomorphic.